# Change filename on custom monolog file

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-2.8, monolog, symfony-2.7

I use a rotating monolog handler

```
monolog:
        channels: ['import']
        handlers:
            import_client:
                level: debug
                type: rotating_file
                max_files: 10
                path: '%kernel.logs_dir%/import.log'
                channels: [import_client]
```

All works fine except I don't like the filename. I get `import-2018-02-22.log`.
Does it exist a way to change this format?

I would like the filename to be like `import-"date(YmdHis)".log`.

Is possible to rewrite the filename format? Did you have any solutions ?

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution, need to add in config handler a new parameter :

```
date_format: 'YmdHms'
```

Answer (score 0):

The RotatingFileHandler Logs records to a file and creates one logfile **per day**. It will also delete files older than $maxFiles. You should use [logrotate](https://linux.die.net/man/8/logrotate) for high profile setups though, this is just meant as a quick and dirty solution.

As you can see in the original [RotatingFileHandler](https://github.com/Seldaek/monolog/blob/master/src/Monolog/Handler/RotatingFileHandler.php): you could possibly change the rotate dateformat

```
public function setFilenameFormat($filenameFormat, $dateFormat)
```

But I don't see any configuration option in the [symfony monolog reference](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/monolog.html).
You could call a service using

```
services:
    app.custom_rotating_service:
        # ...
        calls:
            - method: setFilenameFormat
              arguments:
                  - 'yourFilenameFormat'
                  - 'Ymd'
```

It seems to me you would get into soemthing complex for no added value of a date format.

**TLDR**

- It's not possible to have a logfile By Hour/Minute with monolog
- Changing Date format or the rotation frequency to months/year of the handler **seems (to me)** doable but not supported by the symfony monolog configuration.  you could create a service and try to call the method automatically on service isntance creation
- You should use [logrotate](https://linux.die.net/man/8/logrotate) if you have a custom need of rotating log

Comment: It's possible to change this dateFormat from config ? Or need to create a new service ?

Comment: Changing Date format or the rotation frequency to months/year of the handler seems (to me) doable but not supported by the symfony monolog configuration, you could create a service and try to call the method automatically

Comment: The service should use my custom handler ?

Comment: I honestly don't know, I don't have the time to try right now. I can't see how you would register the type to use it in monolog yet.  It seems to me you are  getting into something complicated for no added value

Comment: Ok, I tried like you wrote but now work... I will find how can define this service